# Como NÃO separar um número de dois ou mais dígitos ao adicionar em uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho um problema que, ao iterar sobre uma string e ao adicionar apenas os números em uma lista, um número (por exemplo `13`) acaba virando `['1', '3']`.

Como contornar isso e fazer com que o número fique completo, como em `['13']`?

Observe que não tem espaço entre os dígitos para usar o `split`.

```
teste = 'A2B4C13'

listaNumeros = []
for numero in teste:
   if numero.isnumeric():
     listaNumeros.append(numero)
    
print(listaNumeros)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de adicionar o caractere diretamente na lista, você pode criar uma variável de buffer para guardar o valor enquanto for numérico e adicionar a lista apenas quando encontrar uma letra ou finalizar a string:

```py
teste = 'A2B4C13'

listaNumeros = []
buffer = ''

for numero in teste:
  if numero.isnumeric():
    buffer += numero
  elif buffer:
    listaNumeros.append(buffer)
    buffer = ''

if buffer:
  listaNumeros.append(buffer)
  buffer = ''
    
print(listaNumeros)  # ['2', '4', '13']
```

Answer (score 3):

Como alternativa à outra resposta, daria para fazer isso de forma relativamente simples utilizando uma expressão regular:

```
import re

nums = re.findall(r"\d+", "A2B4C13")
print(nums)  # ['2', '4', '13']
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/QHPRSI).</sup>

Basicamente, utiliza-se a função [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) (do módulo de expressões regulares) para buscar por qualquer ocorrência numérica na string.

Answer (score 1):

Você queria salva os numero em uma lista?
Eu fiz dessa forma
não usei listas para junta os caracteres

```
teste = 'A2B4C13'

listaNumeros = ""
listaDeLetras = ""
for numero in teste:
    if numero.isnumeric():
        listaNumeros += numero
    else:
        listaDeLetras += numero

print("Numeros:",listaNumeros)
print("Letras:"+listaDeLetras)
```